# Base Constructor Call in Derived Class

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor

I have got the following problem in a homework for university, the task is as follows:

Derive a class `MyThickHorizontalLine` from `MyLine`. One requirement is that the constructor of the derived class `MyThickHorizontalLine` does not set the values itself, instead its obligated to call the base constructor.

Which currently looks like this in my cpp file:

```
MyThickHorizontalLine::MyThickHorizontalLine(int a, int b, int c)
{
    MyLine(a, b, c, b);
}
```

This is my Base constructor:

```
MyLine::MyLine(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2)
{
    set(x1, y1, x2, y2);
}
```

Header Definition of MyLine:

```
public:
    MyLine(int = 0, int = 0, int = 0, int = 0);
```

Current problem is that when I debug this I step into the constructor of `MyThickHorizontalLine` my values for `a` `b` `c` are for example `1` `2` `3` they are set there and when I then step further and it gets into the Base constructor all my values are Zero.

I am probably missing a crucial part about inheritance here, but I can't get my mind on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> MyThickHorizontalLine::MyThickHorizontalLine(int a, int b, int c)
> {
>      MyLine(a, b, c, b); // <<<< That's wrong
> }
> ```

You cannot initialize your base class inside the constructor's body. Simply use the member initializer list to call the base class constructor:

```
MyThickHorizontalLine::MyThickHorizontalLine(int a, int b, int c) : MyLine(a, b, c, b) {}
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to:

> You cannot initialize your base class inside the constructor's body. Simply use the member initializer list to call the base class constructor:

In other words,

```
MyThickHorizontalLine::MyThickHorizontalLine(int a, int b, int c)
{
     MyLine(a, b, c, b); // <<<< This is temporary local object creation, like that one:
     MyLine tmp = MyLine(a, b, c, b);
}
```